# How to do Android application testing on Slow Internet on a real Device?

Tags: android, testing

I want to test my application while using slow Internet.

is there a way to explicitly make the Internet slow? Any genuine application that can slow the internet.

I am currently using Wifi. I could use my data pack and i can switch it to 3G or 2G but couldn't find any signal.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to route your traffic thru anything that that would lwt you shape the traffic. Be it smarter access point with such feature or linux box acting as gateway with traffic shaper.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it much better? I am new to networking. I am looking for an android application that could slow down the traffic. Plus I have an unrooted device.